# Использование HTTPS ASP.NET через docker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, docker

Подскажите как использовать https для доступа к ASP.NET Core 2.1, запущенного через докер(на digital ocean сервере). Сертификат есть(использую его для IdentityServer4), docker на ubuntu 16.4

Comment: Порт сразу наружу слушает или используете nginx?

Comment: Сразу наружу слушает

Comment: Удобней и надежней будет использовать обратный прокси nginx, на нем и настраивайте сертификаты.

Comment: Это его как отдельный контейнер запускать надо и настраивать взаимодействие?

Comment: Ну, у вас есть root доступ к системе?

Comment: Да, конечно, кстати по ключу.

Comment: Тогда [здесь первоначальная настройка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) и [например вот тут](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/7031640) как настроить с сертификатом. Nginx не обязательно ставить в контейнере.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас пройдусь

Comment: Там вариант без докера, а у меня приложение в контейнере запускается. Наверняка надо сам контейнер запускать с какими-то предустановками. На windows  докер контейнер запускается под https по дефолту.